# Why only one periodic task created?

Tags: python-3.x, celery, periodic-task

I want to create multiple periodic tasks by a loop, but only the last of the list was created.For example:

```
@app.on_after_finalize.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    a = [1,3,4,7,8,10]
    for i in a:
        sender.add_periodic_task(crontab(hour=i), task.s())
```

In the task schedule when I run celery beat -A tasks - l debug, I see only the task executed at 10 o'clock. Why?

Comment: I think that you can schedule all the tasks with the same instruction:
`sender.add_periodic_task(crontab(hour=[1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 10]), task.s())`

in the docs, they say that hour can be a list in the crontab parameter:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.1-archived/reference/celery.schedules.html

Answer (score 3):

The tasks are stored in a dictionary by key.  The key is given by the `name` argument or the `repr()` of the `sig` argument.  Here the `sig` argument is `task.s()` and it is the same for every loop.  So as it goes through the loop it overwrites the same key for each schedule.  To fix provide a unique name:

```
sender.add_periodic_task(crontab(hour=i), task.s(), name='whatever-{}'.format(i))
```

Here is the [relevent source](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/app/base.html#Celery.add_periodic_task) from `celery`:

```
def add_periodic_task(self, schedule, sig,
                      args=(), kwargs=(), name=None, **opts):
    key, entry = self._sig_to_periodic_task_entry( 
        schedule, sig, args, kwargs, name, **opts)
    if self.configured:
        self._add_periodic_task(key, entry)
    else:
        self._pending_periodic_tasks.append((key, entry))

    return key

def _sig_to_periodic_task_entry(self, schedule, sig,
                                args=(), kwargs={}, name=None, **opts):
    sig = (sig.clone(args, kwargs)
           if isinstance(sig, abstract.CallableSignature)
           else self.signature(sig.name, args, kwargs))
    return name or repr(sig), { # <------------------------------- key created here
        'schedule': schedule,
        'task': sig.name,
        'args': sig.args,
        'kwargs': sig.kwargs,
        'options': dict(sig.options, **opts),
    }

def _add_periodic_task(self, key, entry):
    self._conf.beat_schedule[key] = entry # <--------------------- key can be overwritten
```

**edit:**  As pointed out by @GharianiMohamed [the docs state](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.1-archived/reference/celery.schedules.html#celery.schedules.crontab.hour) that the `hour` argument of `chrontab` can be "*a (list of) integers from 0-23 that represent the hours of a day of when execution should occur.*"  So a better way of handling this to remove the loop entirely:

```
@app.on_after_finalize.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    a = [1,3,4,7,8,10]
    sender.add_periodic_task(crontab(hour=a), task.s())
```

Comment: If i have a list of time object,  I want to add periodic tasks based on the time objects which have particular hours 
and minutes then I need to add it manually?